# Coming out of beta

Tags: discussion

I tried to find the answer to how we come out of beta, and eventually ended up on the [Proposal page on Area51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/5728?phase=beta). So I saw that some of the stats weren't that great and thought that this was the reason for the site being stuck in beta for so long. But then I saw that it says "This site has finished its beta and will be launching very soon."

Does anyone know when this is going to happen? Does it have to do with the merge?

Comment: stats are now (Aug 5)more than decent, and the birthday of beta is coming (in 5 day). Time to switch ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OK, I will get the Area 51 team to change that to

> This site will remain in beta indefinitely so it can grow; we will continue to evaluate its site statistics and overall health.

There are three *minimum* requirements before a site can qualify for graduation:

- +90 days in beta
- Enough voting to create 10 Editors (users with +2,000 rep)
- Enough voting to create 5 Closers (users with +3,000 rep)

If you read the blog post about graduating sites: [**When Will My Site Graduate?**](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/when-will-my-site-graduate/), it says essentially that, as long as you continue to make progress, *we'll wait for as long as it takes.*

In the meantime:

1. Share great questions and answers
   http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/announcer-booster-and-publicist-badges/
2. Vote, vote, vote
   http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/vote-early-vote-often/
3. Love and reward your new users for being awesome!
   https://ux.stackexchange.com/review

Comment: Thanks @Jeff! Concerning the sharing mechanism, please read [this question](http://ui.stackexchange.com/q/4287/3643) I just posted on UI (wasn't sure whether to post it here or there).

Comment: +1 for Vote, vote, vote!

Comment: I see that the site is now public, according to the status on Area 51, but the UX logo on the main site still has `beta` at the end. This beta text should be removed!

Comment: @awe I believe it is still in beta: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/5728/user-experience and here note the word "beta" http://stackexchange.com/sites#ux

Comment: Oh.. yes, sorry. My mistake.

Comment: After 443 days in beta the stats are now almost entirely green (with the exception of an "Okay" on 8.6 QPD.) Are the sites monitored automatically for an all-green or is action required?